# Algorithm to extract nodes of same class efficiently from a vector

Tags: python, algorithm

i have a vector (it is the results of a classification  )
which it means  i and s[i] , are in the same class

for example:

```
S=(2,1,1,3,6,7,5,9,6,13,12,14,12,11)

((   `s[1]=2 `so node 1 and 2 are in same class
and    `s[2]=1`  same information
s[3]=1` so all 1,2,3 are in same class))
```

now i have to find a way to get a membership vector from s:
to see which nodes are in same class together

```
mVC=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3]

(here 1,2,3,4 are in one class)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vector `S` looks like it represents a parent relationship, although it may contain cycles. So, if you consider this vector as if it is an adjacency list of a directed graph, and ran depth-first search (DFS) on this data structure, you would find the connected components of this *graph*, each of which would belong to the same class, by your terminology. You can also fill `mVC` while running the DFS, and obtain the data in the format you desire.

As opposed to the default DFS, though, you need to keep an eye out for a *back edge* or a *cross edge*, and update the classification of the nodes that are currently being explored, whenever one of those types of edges is encountered.

A sample implementation is below. When a back edge or a cross edge is encountered, the algorithm stops the recursion and *bubbles up* the component (i.e. classification info) of the destination of that edge, to the vertices that are currently being explored.

```
def dfs(S, u, mVC, currentComponent):
    mVC[u] = currentComponent
    if mVC[ S[u] ] == 0:
        mVC[u] = dfs(S, S[u], mVC, currentComponent)
    else:
        mVC[u] = mVC[S[u]]
    return mVC[u]

S = [0] + list(S) # to handle the 1-indexing of the content in S
mVC = [0] * len(S)
currentComponent = 1
for i in range(1, len(S)):
    if mVC[ i ] == 0:
        componentAssigned = dfs(S, i, mVC, currentComponent)
        if componentAssigned == currentComponent:
            currentComponent += 1
mVC = mVC[1:] # Gets rid of the dummy 0th element added above
# at this point, mVC contains the class relationship in the desired format
```

Comment: yes it is a graph ,but its directed ,so if one node is connect to another they are in same class .is DFS it still work?

Comment: Whether it is directed or not does not really change anything for the DFS algorithm, though. My answer also considers the graph to be directed, and it should work without any issues.

Comment: @somaye I previously overlooked a case in the DFS, but I have now fixed it. You may observe the execution of the code [here](https://ideone.com/GpYM3k).

Comment: i tried to run your code ,but results weren't true,now i run new one and its perfect.thank you very much

Comment: In that case, you may want to reconsider your preference for the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) problem. Here's one approach:

```
S=(2,1,1,3,6,7,5,9,6,13,12,14,12,11)
```

Build a list of tuples, each of them representing edges in the graph, and consisting on the index of a given value in `S` and the value itself:

```
edges = [(ix+1, i) for ix, i in enumerate(S)]
# [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 5), (8,....
```

Build a network using `networkx` and extract its [`connected_components`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_components.html). This will group nodes "in the same class" together:

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edges)
list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

**Output**

```
[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}]
```

Comment: thanks!but it would be better if i could do it without building a new graph. may data set is big and i should repeat this part lots of times!

Comment: Well this is the simpler solution I could think of for this problem. Why multiple times? Do you have multiple lists for which you'd have to repeat the process? This should be reasonably fast even creating a graph anew several times

Comment: this vector is results of a classification and the algorithm generate it lots of time and compare them to get the best accuracy. also i should change that last vector to mVC ,but if its fast enough,then its okay.i should finish whole the code first i think